R : setGeneric with two different S4 classes (B inherits A) with same method name and signature
There is two classes A & B.
B extends A.
There is a method doStuffs for A and one for B.
They have same name and signature except they work on different object and accordingly they do different stuffs.
setClass(
  Class = "A",
  slots = list(
    a = "character",
    b = "character"
  )
)

setGeneric("doStuffs", signature ="obj",
    function(obj,...) standardGeneric("doStuffs")
)
setClass(
  Class = "B",
  contains = "A",
  slots = list(
    c = "character"
  )
)

setGeneric("doStuffs", signature ="obj",
    function(obj,...) standardGeneric("doStuffs")
)

When I call :
obj <- new A(a="a",b="b")
showMethods("doStuffs")
doStuffs(obj)


Function: doStuffs (package blahblah)
obj="B"


unable to find an inherited method for function
‘doStuffs’ for signature ‘obj = "A"’

If I use the following code for both generics, it works.
Don't know why.
showMethods find both generics.
if (!isGeneric("doStuffs")) {
    if (is.function("doStuffs")) {
        fun <- doStuffs
    } else {
        fun <- function(obj, ...) standardGeneric("doStuffs")
    }


Function: doStuffs (package blahblah)
obj="A"
obj="B"

Why does this work ? How to code this the "good way" ?
Updated :
I also have doStuffs method for each classes:
setMethod("doStuffs", "A", function(obj, x1,x2,x3) {}
setMethod("doStuffs", "B", function(obj, x4,x2,x3) {}


Where is your setMethod call? Should have something like setMethod("doStuffs", "A", function(obj) obj@a). Also obj <- new A(a="a",b="b") is the wrong syntax. I would have expected obj <- new("A", a="a",b="b"). You should only be calling setGeneric once; not once per class.

Also,  signature in your call to setMethod (not setGeneric, as pointed out by @MrFlick) defines the class of each argument, not the name.

@MrFlick Is this pattern working when A & B classes are not inherited ? I 'm not succeeding to make it work with another situation where method names are the same for different objects from classes not related. No contains in setClass B.

If they don't inherit, then you need to make sure to have separate setMethod() calls for each class.

You mean two different names doStuffsA and doStuffsB ?!

As discussed in comments, you are misusing setGeneric (and not using setMethod).
Based on the class definitions you provide, first define the generic:
setGeneric(
  "doStuffs",
  function(obj,...) standardGeneric("doStuffs")
)
"doStuffs"

Now define a couple of objects
obj1 <- new ("A", a = "A", b = "B")
obj2 <- new ("B", a = "C", b = "D")

Next, define a method for the superclass ...
setMethod(
  "doStuffs",
  signature = signature(obj = "A"),
  def = function(obj) {
    "Hello from A"
  }
)

... and see what happens:
doStuffs(obj1)
[1] "Hello from A"
doStuffs(obj2)
[1] "Hello from A"

This is correct: there is no doStuffs method for  the subclass, so objects of the subclass use the method of the superclass.
Now define a method for class B ...
setMethod(
  "doStuffs",
  signature = signature(obj = "B"),
  def = function(obj) {
    "Hello from B"
  }
)

... and repeat.
doStuffs(obj1)
[1] "Hello from A"
doStuffs(obj2)
[1] "Hello from B"

All good.
I think the S4 Chapter of Hadley's Advanced R is well worth a read.  And several re-reads.

This answer was written before OP's update that added calls to setMethod.

I ended up with one setGeneric("doStuffs", signature="obj",     function(obj, ...) standardGeneric("doStuffs") ) and I have two methods with two diferents signatures relative to the two different classes. I works now.  Thanks
